# Multiple show/hide scrollable containers

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, hide, show

In my example here:

**[Example](http://codepen.io/cvaneenige/pen/RWpEdJ)**

JS

```
$('button').on('click', showHide);
$('.overlay').on('click', showHide);

function showHide(){
  $('.scroll-container').toggleClass('show');
  $('.content-container').toggleClass('no-scroll');
  $('.overlay').toggleClass('opacity');
  }
```

you have a basic body with text. A clickable element (in this case a 'button') causes a scrollable container to appear and 'hover' over the original body, which can be hidden again by clicking outside of this container.

I'm not very good at JavaScript and with this example I was helped by a friend. The thing I'm struggling with now is that I need multiple different clickable elements, displaying a similar scrolling container, but with different content.

I'm doing this for a portfolio website, so imagine a bunch of photos on a page, which when clicked result in a body hovering over the original content, further elaborating the clicked project.
Do I create multiple id's for each project, together with multiple scrolling container id's, and just copy the JavaScript a couple of times?

I hope this makes sense and I hope someone is capable of explaining to me how I'm able to create the proposed effect.

Comment: Provide your source code.

Comment: I'm sorry, it should be fixed now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you have to make a connection between buttons and containers that should be opened. One way is to use their indexes, so that when first button is clicked, first container would open. You can use `this` reference of the clicked object inside your function, in order to get its index. Like this:

```
$(this).index()
```

Then, you have to select all the elements with `scroll_container` class  `$('.scroll-container')` and reduce the set of matched elements to the one by passing index of the clicked element to [`.eq()`](https://api.jquery.com/eq/) method `.eq($(this).index())`. Finally, you have to add `show` class to it `addClass('show')`.

And because the logic is changed, you have to separate actions done on `button` and `.overlay` click events. They do not make a reverse action now, so they are not "togglers" anymore.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LpWwJL

```
$('button').on('click', show);
$('.overlay').on('click', hide);

function show(){   
   $('.scroll-container').eq($(this).index()).addClass('show');
   $('.content-container').addClass('no-scroll');
   $('.overlay').addClass('opacity');
}

function hide() {
   $('.scroll-container').removeClass('show');
   $('.content-container').removeClass('no-scroll');
   $('.overlay').removeClass('opacity');
}
```

**UPDATE**

One thing you should keep in mind regarding `$(this).index()` method. 
As it is written [here](https://api.jquery.com/index/):

> If no argument is passed to the .index() method, the return value is an integer indicating the position of the first element within the jQuery object relative to its sibling elements.

That means that trigger elements should have common parent in order to maintain our logic.

In cases like this: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/32946956/edit, elements that are triggering `scroll_container` appearance, have different parent nodes (they are placed in 3 different `divs`). So, if we will call `index()` method for each of them, it will return '0' because they are the first and the only elements in their parent nodes.

Actually it means that you have to get the order of their parent elements, not theirs own. This can be achieved by using `parent()` method before `index()`:

```
$(this).parent().index()
```

Here is updated [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pjPgpm?editors=101).

Comment: I'm befuddled, this is essentially what I need. I do not understand how you managed to create three separate scroll-containers and how you linked them to the individual buttons however.
I need more of these separate clickable buttons and linked scroll-containers, could you explain what exactly is going on?

Comment: I'm sorry for my late response, I have been busy trying to understand it for the past hour now, but for me being as new to JavaScript as I am I do not fully understand it yet.
I want a scroll-container to open with clicking on the associated element (which in my case will be an .img), and to hide when clicked off of the scroll-container. It worked with the buttons, I only do not understand how to apply this with images.

With what I tried now, the images are responsive, but only Header1 shows up. I must be doing something wrong with the indexes, but I'm not sure what. Could you help me?

Comment: Here it is. As you can see I have replaced the first three buttons with .img's just to try it out. It's responsive, but not showing the right scroll-container.
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dYWGNN

Comment: Incredible, I would'nt have thought of the parent method, thanks for elaborating Lazarev! I've been breaking my head around this all day, I'm glad it finally sort of works.

I have one final question; now that the images are fully responsive, I do notice a 'jump' back to the top of the page when the scroll-container becomes shown. How do I edit it in the CSS so that this doesn't happen? This didn't happen in my previous try-outs. Is it a certain position set (fixed?)?

Comment: Glad to help you. I can't reproduce situation you've described because there are invalid images in the provided codepen. I assume that it is because of the scrolling bar being changed. And I think that it should be a separate question for css ninjas  :)

Comment: I'll try and fix it by myself, but I'm building up the entire website now and it's working. Thanks a lot again Lazarev, I really appreciate it. :)

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I would implement a generic function to display a different content using the same function based in the button. So for that we will need something to relational the click with the content for that we can set a value in out button:

```
<button data-id="1">Click me 1!</button>
<button data-id="2">Click me 2!</button>
```

so out when we click the button we should get the value to send it to our function:

```
    $('button').on('click', function(){
        var dataButtonValue = $(this).data('id');
    });
```

Then we can match it with the content using for example `data-content-id`

```
<div class="content" data-content-id="1">your wording</div>
<div class="content" data-content-id="2">your wording</div>
```

With all that we can manage what content we want to show depends on the click.

```
function showHide(id){
    $('.content[data-content-id="' + id + '"]').toggleClass('show'); 
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/gon250/wL45hr81/)

I hope it's helps.